# How to set precision for all cout in the code block?

Tags: c++, cout

I do not want to use repeatedly use setprecision and fixed on cout. So is there any way can set only one and use it for all cout in the code block?'

```
int main()
{
  double num1 = 1.00000, num2 = 2.00005;
  cout **<< setprecision(5) << fixed <<** num1 << endl; <-- I do not to repeatedly set this.
  cout **<< setprecision(5) << fixed** << num2 << endl;
}
```

I tried below but it does not work

```
int main()
{
   double num1 = 1.00000, num2 = 2.00005;
   cout.precision(5); cout.fixed; cout.showpoint; <-- Does not work
   cout << num1 << endl << num2 << endl;
}
```

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: create a function and pass what you want to cout as  parameter

Answer (score 2):

There is a caveat that setting the `.precision()` and the stream flags `std::fixed` and `std::showpoint`, etc.. will modify the stream flags as indicated by [@dxiv](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5538420/dxiv) in his now deleted answer and modify the stream behavior program-wide. That is important and can have program wide implications regardless where they are set.

Often you want to change the format for a limited purpose, such as for all floating point output in a class overload of `<<`, or the *"code block"* as your title indicates, etc... If you make the change in the overloaded member function, it affects `std::cout` throughout the rest your program -- which may not have been intended.

C++ provides a simple mechanism to make the change on a temporary basis by saving the stream `.flags()` before adjusting the stream and then when done, restoring the original flags before you leave the scope where the changes were desired. This will undo the  [std::ios_base::fmtflags](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/fmtflags), e.g. `std::fixed` and `std::showpoint` settings, but the `.precision()` change must be undone by restoring the default value of `6`.

To save the stream flags before making changes you can use:

```
    std::ios_base::fmtflags f = std::cout.flags();      /* save format flags */
```

When done with the output requiring the change you can restore the flags with:

```
    std::cout.flags(f);                                 /* restore saved flags */
```

Restoring the default `.precision()` takes setting the precision back to the default `6`, e.g.

```
    std::cout.precision(6);                             /* restore precision */
```

There are two (actually three) ways to set the format flags. (1) You can use, e.g. `std::fixed`, `std::showpoint`, etc.. individually or (2,3) you can manipulate the flags directly using [std::ios_base::setf](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/setf) or by declaring BitmaskType [std::ios_base::fmtflags](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/fmtflags). To set the `std::fixed` and `std::showpoint` flags directly, you can do:

```
std::cout.setf (std::ios_base::fixed, std::ios_base::showpoint);
```

To use the BitmaskType you would create an instance of the type and the set the value by OR'ing and AND'ing values for the wanted flags. The `.flags()` member function is then used to set the flag values, in the same manner you pass the saved format flags to undue the changes you have made using the saved bitmap of the original flags state. The `std::ios_base::fmtflags` link above provides an example of each of the ways.

Saving before the change and then restoring the flags when done resets the flags regardless of which method you used to set them.

Comment: Shouldn't you query for the current precision and restore that instead of blindly assuming the application uses the default precision elsewhere?

Comment: @clcto - yes, you can do that, but education is a slow revealing of the truth. If you are asked for the time and respond by explaining how to build a clock, the student quickly tunes you out. If you answer their question and provide links to the reference that explains further, you teach them how to fish and feed them for life `:)`

Answer (score 1):

Lets take an example:

```
#include <iostream>
int main () {
double f = 3.14159;
std::cout.unsetf ( std::ios::floatfield );                
std::cout.precision(5);
std::cout << f <<endl;
std::cout.precision(10);
std::cout << f <<endl;
std::cout.setf( std::ios::fixed, std:: ios::floatfield ); 
std::cout << f <<endl;
return 0;
}
```

Now this gives us an output of :

3.1416

3.14159

3.1415900000

Now in your case, the code should look something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
int main () {
double num1 = 1.00000, num2 = 2.00005;
std::cout.unsetf ;                
std::cout.precision(5);
std::cout << num1 <<endl;
std::cout << num2 <<endl;
return 0;
}
```

If the above doesn't work, I think you will have to repeat and once more define the precision.

```
#include <iostream>
int main () {
double num1 = 1.00000, num2 = 2.00005;
std::cout.unsetf ;                
std::cout.precision(5);
std::cout << num1 <<endl;
std::cout.precision(5);
std::cout << num2 <<endl;
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple way to set precision and fixed flag for a block of code:

```cpp
const std::streamsize oldPrecision = std::cout.precision(8);
const std::ios::fmtflags oldFlags = std::cout.setf(std::ios::fixed);

// code here which requires std::cout to print with precision=8 in fixed format

std::cout.precision(oldPrecision);
std::cout.setf(oldFlags);
```